# NSString not updating when notification triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c

My user is able to upload and/or take a photo on their profile (ViewController). That said, once the photo is saved, I want the imageView to be updated with the most recent photo right after saving. In order to do that, I need to refresh the NSString (secondLink). In theory, I'd think the below code would work - e.g. trigger method userpicUpdated upon successful save (method "re-grabs" info from server). That said, for some reason, the below userpicUpdated method is just pulling the old data in field_photo_path, and not the updated data. How can I fix this?

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "DIOSSession.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        [DIOSSession setupDios];

    }
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 - (void)userpicUpdated:(NSNotification *)note {                    

    }



     - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(userpicUpdated:)
                                                     name:@"userpicUpdated" object:nil];

    }

    - (IBAction)savePhotoButton:(id)sender {
          [DIOSUser
         userUpdate:userData
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) { /* Handle successful operation here */


             NSLog(@"User data updated!");
             self.activityInd.hidden = YES;
             [self.activityInd stopAnimating];


             [DIOSUser
              userGet:userData
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) { /* Handle successful operation here */



                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"userpicUpdated" object:nil];

                  NSDictionary *thisUser = userData;
                  NSLog(@"USER DATA GOTTEN %@", thisUser);

                  NSString *imageUpdate = thisUser[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"value"];
                  NSLog(@"IMAGE STRING %@", imageUpdate);

                 NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUpdate];
                  [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
                  NSLog(@"IMAGE URL %@", imageUrl);




              }
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { /* Handle operation failire here */

                  NSLog(@"User data failed to update!");
              }
              ];




         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { /* Handle operation failire here */

          NSLog(@"User data failed to update!");
         }
         ];

        }
```

Comment: Where is the code that re-fetches the user data from the server?  The code here just seems to reference a previously fetched dictionary.

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you expect `user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]` to contain a changed value after some network operation, but how can anyone help without seeing what it was, seeing some code that tries to change it, etc?

Comment: @Paulw11 The user data is fetched in AppDelegate when the app is launched (DIOSSession). See edit above.

Comment: So, don't you need to perform some task to refresh the user?  If you are getting the old data, there is something you aren't doing, but it will be part of the `DIOSUser` object

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the source code on Github](https://github.com/acquia/drupal-create/blob/master/Drupal%20Create/drupal-ios-sdk/DIOSUser.m), `DIOSUser userUpdate:` doesn't reload user info, therefore you would need to make a call to `DIOSUser userGet:` on update success. On `userGet:` success you can then save the returned user data and update the `UIImage` by firing off to `NSNotificationCenter`.

---

Updating the `UIImage` on success, you won't need to use `NSNotificationCenter`. It's also worthwhile checking if the `imageView` is still accessible (has iOS released it from memory?) to avoid crashes.

```
- (IBAction)savePhotoButton:(id)sender {
    [DIOSUser userUpdate:userData
                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
                      NSLog(@"User data updated!");
                      self.activityInd.hidden = YES;
                      [self.activityInd stopAnimating];

                      [DIOSUser userGet:userData
                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
                                    [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] = userData;
                                    NSLog(@"USER DATA GOTTEN %@", userData);

                                    NSString *imageUpdate = userData[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"value"];
                                    NSLog(@"IMAGE STRING %@", imageUpdate);

                                    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUpdate];
                                    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
                                     NSLog(@"IMAGE URL %@", imageUrl);
                                }
                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) {
                                     NSLog(@"User data failed to update!");
                                 }];
                  }
                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) {
                       NSLog(@"User data failed to update!");
                  }];

}
```

Where are you initially setting `[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]` or where are you first setting `userData`. Could you show that code?

From the source code I can't see that `userData` is automatically updated on `userGet:`. I would have thought you need to set `userData` to data returned in `response`. Can you do an `NSLog(@"Response %@", response);` and see if that matches the current `userData`?

Comment: Ahhh makes sense. Okay, see edit. Now I'm just unsure about what I should be putting in my NSNotification method? Eg. updating the image string works and the updated value is returned...but when I change screens and go back, the image is back to the old value. I update it on userGet success - what am I missing?

Comment: @Brittany I've never used Drupal or it's SDK so can only base this off quickly looking over the source. Based on your edit it would seem that your `UIViewController` sets the `UIImage` when it becomes active from the value stored in `[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user]`, however `user` on `sharedSession` still contains the old data as you have only used the response locally. Have a look over my edited answer where instead of a local declaration of `thisUser`, its set to the `sharedSession` `user` instead.